# how do i get a list of all combinations for both words given?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i was trying to come up with a way to get a list of words like "yes" in all possible (but common) ways like lower cased and upper case and capitalized .
and then i found out you cant put two words in this function (the words "sup" & "hello") .
is there a way possible to be able to have all the words in one list with this function or should start over ?

```
def case_insensetive(text) :
    insensetive_string = [text.lower(),text.upper(),text.capitalize()]
    print (insensetive_string)

try :
   case_insensetive("sup","hello")
except :
   raise Exception ("you screwed something")
```

Comment: What output do you expect for `case_insensetive("sup","hello")`?

Comment: You can: use `def case_insensetive(text1, text2):` and then use those variables instead inside the function.

Comment: something like ("sup","SUP","Sup","hello","HELLO","Hello")

Comment: Possible letter: accept a list (of strings) inside your function, and call it as such: `case_insensetive(["sup", "hello"])`. Then inside your function, iterate over the words inside the list.

Comment: NB: the spelling is insensitive; three i's, one e. Perhaps it doesn't matter, but it is incredibly distracting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass an arbitrary parameter(*args)..then take it can any numbers of arguments..

```
def case_insensetive(*texts):
    insensetive_string = []
    for text in texts:
        insensetive_string+=[text.lower(),text.upper(),text.capitalize()]
    print(insensetive_string)

case_insensetive("sup",'hello')
```

*Output: ['sup', 'SUP', 'Sup', 'hello', 'HELLO', 'Hello']*

Answer (score 4):

This is a typical job for the [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function.

Also, use `return` instead of `print` in your function.

```
def case_insensetive(text):
    insensetive_string = [text.lower(),text.upper(),text.capitalize()]
    return insensetive_string


words = ['yes', 'hello']

r = list(map(case_insensetive, words))

print(r)
```

Output:

```
[['yes', 'YES', 'Yes'], ['hello', 'HELLO', 'Hello']]
```

If you want a single list, instead of a nested one:

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in r for item in sublist]
print(flat_list)

['yes', 'YES', 'Yes', 'hello', 'HELLO', 'Hello']
```

Comment: oh thanks , it worked ! but why should you make another list containing the other two lists ?

Comment: @nightmare008 Answered that as well.